# Can SQL remove duplicates within fields rather than records?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Is SQL the correct tool to be removing duplicates in fields?

I have an access database and I'm looking to remove the fields where the data is the same in the same field in each record.

So, for example I might have this:

```
-------------------------------
|PN   |SU     |DE        |TD  |
-------------------------------
|1001 |A      |Widget    |Red |
|1002 |A      |WidgetS   |Red |
|1003 |A      |WidgetL   |Red |
-------------------------------
```

which is the result of

```
SELECT [PN],[SU],[DE],[TD] FROM tbl WHERE ([PN] IN ('1001','1002','1003'))
```

In this case I dont want anything returned from the `[SU]` and `[TD]` fields as these all contain the same data.

Is there anything that can be done to the query to not return anything in fields where the data is the same across all records so that the results would look like this?

```
------------------
|PN   |DE        |
------------------
|1001 |Widget    |
|1002 |WidgetS   |
|1003 |WidgetL   |
------------------
```

Is SQL the correct tool to be doing this or am I better off post processing this data once the results are in???

Comment: So if `TD` had different vlaues, you would want to see the data, but if they are all the same you don't?

Comment: With the given sample, all you have to do is not include SU and TD fields in query to get the desired output. It is not clear what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Build a report and use textbox HideDuplicates property.

Comment: @June7 the problem is that I don't know not to include `SU` and `TD` fields in the query as I don't know they'll have duplicate values!!  If I knew that in the first place, I would exclude them from the query...  @Nick.McDermaid yes you are correct; if they contained data which was not the same across all fields, I would want to see them.

Comment: Inclusion of field in query cannot be dynamic - it's either there or it isn't. Queries are not intended to be presentation vehicle. As I said, build a report.

Comment: I agree, queries are not intended to be presentation vehicle, you should use a reporting tool for this. Failing that, you'd have more success if you left the column there but blanked out the values. Is this acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

As one of the commenters indicated, the results of a Query have a fixed number of fields, and you cannot change that dynamically. However, if you find it useful, you can make the field content become "void" when all the results are the same. "Void" can be an empty string, a Null or whatever you want. You can achieve this using a subquery as the result for each of the fields. The SQL code that would do this is the following:

```
SELECT   [PN]
       , Iif((SELECT Min(tbl.SU) <> Max(tbl.SU) FROM tbl WHERE ([PN] IN ('1001','1002','1003')) GROUP BY tbl.SU), tbl.SU, "") AS [SU]
       , [DE]
       , Iif((SELECT Min(tbl.TD) <> Max(tbl.TD) FROM tbl WHERE ([PN] IN ('1001','1002','1003')) GROUP BY tbl.TD), tbl.TD, "") AS [TD]
FROM tbl 
WHERE ([PN] IN ('1001','1002','1003'))
```

If you want more information about SQL aggregate functions, you can check the example queries from the Access file downloadable from the web site [LightningGuide.net](https://LightningGuide.net).

The above code works well if the results of TD and SU are never Null. In case you can have Null results, you can also achieve the same result, but you need to write slightly more complex expressions instead of:

```
Min(xxx) <> Max(xxx)
```